# Subscribed function in RXJS never called

Tags: javascript, rxjs

So I have html like so:

```
<div id='result'>Start</div>
```

and javascript copy-pasted from the markdown on github:

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');

var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

var subscription = source.subscribe(function (e) {
  result.innerHTML = e.clientX + ', ' + e.clientY;
});
```

aaaand...nothing happens. The div's html never changes, setting a breakpoint in the dev tools in the subscribed lambda never triggers. No errors/warnings. Stepping through the constructor call on line 3 did not yield any insight, seems like everything got wired up appropriately. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is much simpler than Rx (your RxJS usage is fine here btw). Is it possible this code is placed _above_ the `<div id='result'` bit? If so, try putting the `var result = ...` part _inside_ the subscribe.

Comment: Just did, no help. And although I didn't wrap the scripts in a DOM ready handler, the tags are at the bottom of the page and stepping through it in the debugger everything looks defined properly at the point of use. I'm just frustrated because I literally copied this straight from the docs. I'm currently fetching rxjs via cdn, I'm going to try cloning the git repo instead and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Were you using 4.0.1? There was a bug in it that version that broke `fromEvent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Was pulling RXJS from cloudflare and it apparently was a different version than the current documentation is written for.